AG Grid Floating Filter with Material UI Autocomplete Keyboard Navigation not Working
Current behavior
When using the arrow up and down keys in the floating filter with an autocomplete component, the keyboard interaction is not working as expected.
AG Grid version:
30.2.1 and 31.3.1
Expected behavior
Using the up and down arrow keys navigate through the autocomplete suggestions within the floating filter.  Note: This functionality currently works correctly in other areas of the application, but not specifically within the floating filter.
Reproduction:
A codesandbox demonstrating the issue can be found here:
https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/custom-filter-and-floating-filter-forked-xtr7mx
